# How to get a checked radio button to do different functions on the canvas in JS & html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, radio-button

I'm trying to use radio buttons to define what the user can do to an object on the canvas. Here is part of the code that defines a button moveVector that when clicked will allow the user to move some arrows on the screen when they are clicked and dragged. I eventually want there to be separate buttons for rotating and scaling the arrows but I want it to be dependent on what radio button is selected. I have tried this code below but it just does nothing. No error codes. It worked before I added the button so I know it must be an error in applying the checked button option. Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

```
    <td><input name="vectorFunction" type="radio" value="moveVector" id="moveVector" onClick="changeVector();"></td>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
              context = canvas.getContext('2d');
              mouse = utils.captureMouse(canvas);
              arrow1 = new Arrow();

                arrow1.x = 500;
                arrow1.y = 500;

          var arrow2 = new Arrow();
          arrow2.x = 300;
          arrow2.y = 300;

          function changeVector() {
              if (document.getElementsById("moveVector").checked == true) {

                canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
                    if (utils.containsPoint(arrow1.getBounds(), mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
                 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
              }
              if (utils.containsPoint(arrow2.getBounds(), mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
                 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp2, false);
                 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove2, false);
              }
           }, false);

                  function onMouseUp() {
                      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
                      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
          }
                  function onMouseUp2() {
                      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp2, false);
                      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove2, false);
          }
                  function onMouseMove (event) {
                      arrow1.x = mouse.x;
                      arrow1.y = mouse.y;
                    }
                  function onMouseMove2 (event) {
                      arrow2.x = mouse.x;
                      arrow2.y = mouse.y;
                  }
              }
              else {
                  //Do nothing
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just a typo in your example, but your if statement looks like this:

`if (document.getElementsById("moveVector").checked == true)`

try changing is to the singular version, since you're looking for that check box, not a list.

ie:

`if (document.getElementById("moveVector").checked == true)`

Comment: Yeah still nothing... Thanks for that tidbit though!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is taking the event listeners outside of the function that checks for the button click since you have to make JS tell html to check if the buttons are checked or not and it can't do that with the canvas listeners locked in a function. Then I removed the ===true part since it was redundant. Here's what worked!

```
<div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
<label>Select one</label>
<input type="radio" name="vfnselect" value="move" id="vmover" checked>Move</label>

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    if (utils.containsPoint(arrow1.getBounds(), mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp1, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseVector1, false);
    }
 }, false);
  function onMouseUp1() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp1, false);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseVector1, false);
  }
function onMouseVector1 (event) {
    if (document.getElementById('vmover').checked) {
      arrow1.x = mouse.x;
      arrow1.y = mouse.y;
    }
```